# Creating a backup for MS Office 2016 by saving a folder is that enough?

Tags: ms-office

I made some search on how to make a backup for my MS office 2016 and I found that I should save this folder in the order to backup it and can restore it

```
C:\Windows\System32\spp\store
```

so my question here, because I don't know much in this point, is that folder is enough to restore the activation? if I replace it with the current file it activates the MS office? or I need the product key if I need it how can I bring it what I have reached in this point is that I use this command to get the last 5 Character from the Product key 
first, I go to the MS office folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16
```

then write this in the command in the same folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16>cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus
```

and it gives me the last 5 character from the product key.
the question also here if i need the product key how to re-active it again after replacing the folder and how to get the complete product key without using the internet

Comment: Don't you need to connect to the internet to validate the Product Key?

Comment: is copying the folder again is enough or i need to validate the key?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I would think that you would need to validate the key when you reinstall Office again.